# Error:(15, 47) error: cannot find symbol variable sample_text

Tags: android, android-studio, error-handling

I am completely new to this so my question might be something "dumb" and simple but I can't find the solution. I am trying to make something very easy but when i am trying to play it on my android device it gives me an error :

> Error:(15, 47) error: cannot find symbol variable sample_text

I attach some screenshots for the code and the error.
[image: error1]

[image: Error]

I would be really grateful for any help!

UPDATE:
I redid the project (copy and paste the XML code) into a new project without using the option for C++ in the beginning and it finally worked!

Comment: post your xml in code format

Comment: you have not set id in any of textview

Answer (score 0):

Your views in the xml does not have id. To be able to `findViewById`, your first need to give id to your views.

```
<TextView
 ....
        android:id="@+id/sample_text"
/>
```

Comment: I don't wanna to recall it again, why should i put id to the textviews? I am asking for education purposes!

Comment: Read the documentation as other point out. Without ID`s your activity don`t know to which view you are referring.  findViewById, does waht the name suggest searches for a view with the ID you pass. And the studio is saying to you- there is no such ID

Answer (score 0):

In your case, all `TextView` element should be specific with different `id`. Otherwise debugger will not know which `textView`  you are referring to.

**Example**

```
<TextView 
    android:id="@+id/sample_text"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at the official android documentation and tutorial, in particular this link answers your question ***why should i put id to the textviews?***

It is well explained what are IDs and why you need them.

[View | Android Developers](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html)

Comment: Oh i will. I am just following a tutorial from udacity and google android developers and i am trying to follow exactly what they are telling and writing (they have a link from a simulator where i copy and paste the xml code in my studio) and in there aren't any id attributes, but i will check and add them myself i guess!